# Align text beneath images

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

Currently I'm working in rails app, 
  [image]
 this is my contributers page, I want name of each members beneath the images on centered. Any help will be apperciated.

> Below is my member.html.erb file

```
<h1>CONTRIBUTORS</h1>

 <div id="contributors_image">
  <%= image_tag "one.jpg" %>
  <%= image_tag "two.jpg" %>
  <%= image_tag "three.jpg" %>
  <%= image_tag "four.jpg" %> 
  <%= image_tag "five.jpg" %> 
  <%= image_tag "six.jpg" %> 
  <%= image_tag "seven.jpg" %> 
 </div>
```

> and my part of application.css.scss is,

```
#contributors_image {
        float: centre;
        margin-left: 3em;
        img {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            border-radius: 8.35em;
        }
    }
```

Comment: There's no `float: centre;` Where did you get that from?

Comment: Just curious to know the reason you accepted the other answer. `:)` Just curious. `:D`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

float:centre is not a valid css property. All you need is to encapsulate the image and label that contains the name in it's on div or container and give that container a text-align: center;

```
.img-container{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align:center;
}

img{
    border-radius:100%;
    width:200px;
    float:left;
    margin: 0 20px;
}
```

HTML would look like this after compiled

```
<h1>CONTRIBUTORS</h1>

<div id="contributors_image">
    <div class="img-container">
        <img src="http://fineartamerica.com/images/artworkgallerylogos/yosemite-national-park-science-source-images-1404150568.jpg" />
        <h4>John Doe</h4>
    </div>  
    <div class="img-container">
        <img src="http://fineartamerica.com/images/artworkgallerylogos/yosemite-national-park-science-source-images-1404150568.jpg" />
        <h4>John Doe</h4>
    </div>  
    <div class="img-container">
        <img src="http://fineartamerica.com/images/artworkgallerylogos/yosemite-national-park-science-source-images-1404150568.jpg" />
        <h4>John Doe</h4>
    </div>  
    <div class="img-container">
        <img src="http://fineartamerica.com/images/artworkgallerylogos/yosemite-national-park-science-source-images-1404150568.jpg" />
        <h4>John Doe</h4>
    </div>  
    <div class="img-container">
        <img src="http://fineartamerica.com/images/artworkgallerylogos/yosemite-national-park-science-source-images-1404150568.jpg" />
        <h4>John Doe</h4>
    </div>  
    <div class="img-container">
        <img src="http://fineartamerica.com/images/artworkgallerylogos/yosemite-national-park-science-source-images-1404150568.jpg" />
        <h4>John Doe</h4>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Follow the [**demo**](http://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/xRLjVa) for guidance but you'll have to modify it to your specific markup that will be compiled from your code

Comment: Why do you use `<h4>` mate?

Comment: It is the most common approach for what you want to use. p tags refer to paragraph content. These names would be considered headings. But essentially you can use p tags too. SEO would be happier with h4 is you are interested in that

Comment: Oh. Didn't know that. Thanks for explaining... `:D`

Answer (score 2):

There's no `float: center;` at all. You may do this instead.

- Make the images to be `display: inline-block;`.
- Put a `text-align: center;` to the container.
- Also, it is a good practise to use Sentence case and style it with `text-transform: uppercase;`.

Your final code should look like:

```css
h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#contributors_image {
  margin-left: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}
#contributors_image img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h1>Contributors</h1>

<div id="contributors_image">
  <img src="//placehold.it/100?text=Image+1" alt="Image 1" />
  <img src="//placehold.it/100?text=Image+2" alt="Image 2" />
  <img src="//placehold.it/100?text=Image+3" alt="Image 3" />
  <img src="//placehold.it/100?text=Image+4" alt="Image 4" />
  <img src="//placehold.it/100?text=Image+5" alt="Image 5" />
  <img src="//placehold.it/100?text=Image+6" alt="Image 6" />
  <img src="//placehold.it/100?text=Image+7" alt="Image 7" />
</div>
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]

It now beautifully shows it like expected.

---

You haven't added any names in your code. If you want to do that, you can wrap it with another `<figure>` and `<figcaption>` and do it this way (this is the right way):

```css
h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#contributors_image {
  margin-left: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}
#contributors_image figure {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}
#contributors_image img {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h1>Contributors</h1>

<div id="contributors_image">
  <figure>
    <img src="//placehold.it/200?text=Image+1" alt="Image 1" />
    <figcaption>Contributor 1</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="//placehold.it/200?text=Image+2" alt="Image 2" />
    <figcaption>Contributor 2</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="//placehold.it/200?text=Image+3" alt="Image 3" />
    <figcaption>Contributor 3</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="//placehold.it/200?text=Image+4" alt="Image 4" />
    <figcaption>Contributor 4</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="//placehold.it/200?text=Image+5" alt="Image 5" />
    <figcaption>Contributor 5</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="//placehold.it/200?text=Image+6" alt="Image 6" />
    <figcaption>Contributor 6</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="//placehold.it/200?text=Image+7" alt="Image 7" />
    <figcaption>Contributor 7</figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]

It now beautifully shows it like expected.